# How to escape single quote on MSSQL query into JDBC variable

Tags: jmeter

Using JDBC at Jmeter I need to escape single quote performed on variable.

[image]

My original query is:

`select id from [Teams] where name = '${team}'`.

But, when I got a team like: **Ain M'lila**, the query is not executed

What I tried, and not working is:

```
DECLARE @NevName nvarchar
SET @NevName = REPLACE({${team}, '''', ''''''')
select id from [test8].[Team] where name = @NevName
```

Any solution is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Dmitri T for his efforts, but the solution for me was:

JSR223 PreProcessor: and inside:

```
String userString = vars.get("team");
String changedUserString = userString.replace("'","''");
vars.put("teamChanged", changedUserString);
```

and then used as into the query:

```
select id from [test8].[Team] where name = '${teamChanged}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to escape a single quote you need to [add another single quote to it](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-escape-single-quote/)

In particular your case you can escape `'` with an extra `'` using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('team').replaceAll("\'"\, "''"),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Can u use this function in JDBC request?

Comment: You can use [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) anywhere in Test Plan, they will be evaluated in place when JMeter reaches the function. More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: when I try to use select id from [test8].[Team] where name = '${__groovy(vars.get('team').replaceAll("\'"\, "''"),)}' I got: Cannot invoke method replaceAll() on null object

Comment: It means that your `${team}` variable doesn't have any value (it's [null](https://dev.to/dj_devjournal/understanding-null-in-java-4o31)), you can see JMeter Variables with their respective values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination